# SBT. Выполнить Scala метод

Tags: scala, sbt

Разбираюсь с `managed resources`.
Допустим у меня есть простой объект:

```
package main    

object MySingleObject {
    def getStr: String = "Я что-то делаю, потом возвращаю строку"    
}
```

Теперь я хочу записать результат в файл через `SBT`:

```
//build.sbt
resourceGenerators in Compile += Def.task {
    val file = (resourceManaged in Compile).value / "test.txt"
    IO.write(file, MySingleObject.getStr)
    Seq(file)
}.taskValue
```

Все падает с ошибкой:

> error: not found: value MySingleObject
>   IO.write(file, MySingleObject.getStr)
>   ^
>   [error] Type error in expression

Понятно что как-то надо импортировать `MySingleObject`, но не понятно как

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Расположи `MySingleObject` в папке `project` твоего проекта. `build.sbt` видит `.scala` файлы там расположенные.

Comment: `MySingleObject` использует другие классы в проекте. Которые теперь ему не видны. Как быть в таком случае?

Comment: Если они нужны тебе на момент запуска *sbt* - тебе нужно перенести их в папку `project` тоже. В крайнем случае можно создать сбт-плагин (лучше не спеши).

Comment: Так мне так весь проект целиком придется перенести

Comment: А зачем тебе доступ к проекту на момент запуска sbt? Может твоя задача как раз для плагина?
Грубо говоря - sbt не обязана ничего знать о проекте пока не дашь команду `compile`.

Comment: Задачка такая. Есть апи. Каждый раз во время сборки нужно почитать классы, аннотации над методами, и сгенерить документацию(Суть есть строка). Для этого, в читающий объект надо заимпортить, классы, которые необходимо читать, а это пол проекта. Как лучше всего решить такую задачу? Может выбранный мной подход(через таску) изначально не слишком удачен?

Comment: Ключевая штука - `managed resources`. Эта задача учебная, я должен освоить ее на этом примере. Ну и еще немного погрузиться в `sbt` конечно

Comment: Хм, ну звучит как типичная задача для сбт-плагина. Я плагины больше хелло-ворлда не делал, так что читай доки по плагинам и смотри готовые реализации на гитхабе. Ищи плагины которые лазят по коду: возможно *scalariform* (форматирует стиль-кода), возможно *kind-projector* (добавляет синтаксический сахар).

Comment: Благодарю Вас за подсказки